# including gobal variables from different domains and folders

Tags: php

I have 5 domains and on these domains I have different folders which all call a set of identical php variables.  If i want to change the value of these variables i have to modify 11 files one at a time. it would be easier to have a single file with these variables that would work on all my domains and folders. how or is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Create general config file for your projects or use environment variables.